# How to use javascript to count words on a page

Tags: javascript, html

My task is to count words on my page, and the code I have so far is counting letters instead. I'm all out of ideas. Here is what it looks like:

```js
var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
var total_words = 0;
for (i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i++) {
  total_words += profile_values[i].innerHTML.split(' ').length;
}
document.getElementById('word-count').innerHTML = total_words;
```

```html
<div class="profile-value">
  <td>
    <p>I am a profile value</p>
  </td>
</div>

<div id="stats">
  <h3>Stats</h3>
  <span id="word-count" class="large">0</span>
  <br>words found.
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `td` tags are not allowed as children of a `div`. Also note that `innerHTML` should be used when you need to get HTML, but `textContent` is better suited for getting text content (you'll not have to unescape things like `&amp;`, and don't need to strip tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get rid of the newlines and trim any extraneous spaces by using [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```js
var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
var total_words = 0;
for (i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i++) {
  total_words += profile_values[i].innerHTML.trim().split(' ').length;
}
document.getElementById('word-count').innerHTML = total_words;
```

```html
<div class="profile-value">
  <td>
    <p>I am a profile value</p>
  </td>
</div>

<div id="stats">
  <h3>Stats</h3>
  <span id="word-count" class="large">0</span>
  <br>words found.
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this seems to work just fine for me

Answer (score 6):

Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`, [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it, and use a regular expression to split on any (sequence of) white space (including tabs, newlines, ... not only spaces):

```
total_words += profile_values[i].textContent.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
```

```js
var profile_values = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-value');
var total_words = 0;
for (i = 0; i < profile_values.length; i++) {
  total_words += profile_values[i].textContent.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
}
document.getElementById('word-count').innerHTML = total_words;
```

```html
<table><tr class="profile-value">
  <td>
    <p>I am a profile value</p>
  </td>
</tr></table>

<div id="stats">
  <h3>Stats</h3>
  <span id="word-count" class="large">0</span>
  <br>words found.
</div>
```

NB1: `td` tags are not allowed as children of `div`.

NB2: solutions that stick to `innerHTML` will report the wrong number in some cases, like in this example:

```
<table><tr class="profile-value">
  <td style="background: yellow">
    <p>I am a <font color="red">profile </font> value</p>
  </td>
</tr></table>
```

A solution with `innerHTML` will report 11 words while there still are only 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the html by only looking for the text nodes and extracting those, joining them all with no separator, then running the loop you have.